# Sklearn throws ValueError when given a sparse matrix

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, sparse-matrix, one-hot-encoding

My SVM classifier is throwing a Value Error when features are represented with a sparse matrix, but no error if features are represented with a dense one.

I have code that performs One Hot Encoding on my feature sets, and adds the encoded output to a new list of features.  When the output of the One Hot Encoding is converted to a dense array using .toarray(), my SVM classifier runs fine.

However, using dense arrays are non ideal as I have thousands of data points and my computer to run out of memory very quickly.  Therefore, sparse arrays are needed.  If I simply remove the .toarray() from the code below, the output of enc.transform(features) will output a sparse matrix.  However, if I run my SVM classifier, I now get the following error:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

It seems as though something is failing when my SVM tries to fit the data.  Sklearn SVMs accept sparse vectors, so I don't understand what is going wrong.

```
# Perform One Hot Encoding
transformedFeatureList = []
for features in featureList:
    features = np.asarray(features)
    features = features.reshape(1, -1)      
    transformedFeatures = enc.transform(features).toarray() <---Without toarray() the Value Error happens
    transformedFeatureList.append(transformedFeatures)  
featureList = transformedFeatureList

# Seperate data into training and testing set
trainingSet = [[], []]
testSet = [[], []]
if len(featureList) == len(classList):
    for index in range(len(featureList)):
        if random.randint(1, 10) <= 7:
            trainingSet[0].append(featureList[index])
            trainingSet[1].append(classList[index])
        else:
            testSet[0].append(featureList[index])
            testSet[1].append(classList[index])

# Train model and attempt classification
from sklearn import svm
X = trainingSet[0]
y = trainingSet[1]
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y) 

results = {}
for iclass in set(classList):
    results[iclass] = [0, 0]            # index 0 = correct, index 1 = incorrect
if len(testSet[0]) == len(testSet[1]):
    for index in range(len(testSet[0])):
        features = testSet[0][index]
        iclass = testSet[1][index]
        predictedClass = clf.predict([features])[0]

        if predictedClass == iclass:
            results[iclass][0] += 1
        else:
            results[iclass][1] += 1
```

Comment: Please post your complete code.  We need to see where you are calling the SVM implementation.

Comment: Okay @BadZen I added the additional code.

Comment: I have to admit. This is ugly code. Why do all that splitting and co. manually instead of using sklearn's functions? The whole list of arrays approach would make me nervous. Print out at least the shapes before clf.fit() for both approaches.

Comment: What do you mean by splitting and co?

Comment: what's the full stacktrace / what line is the error occuring on?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the ValueError.  Essentially, my "sparse matrix" was super non-legit.  Apparently a dense matrix represented as:

```
dense = [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]]
```

is a legitimate matrix representation, but representing a sparse matrix as:

```
sparse = [*sparse1, *sparse2, * sparse3]

where *sparse represents the output of a function that returns a sparse matrix
```

is not a legitimate matrix representation.  It is simply a list of matrices.

The solution that I found is to use scipy.sparse.vstack to add sparse rows one by one to create the total sparse matrix that I was going for.